# Deque implementation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, linked-list, queue

```
class Element

  attr_accessor :datum,  :prev , :next

  def initialize(datum,next_element=nil, prev_element=nil)
    @datum = datum
    @next = next_element
    @prev = prev_element
  end

end

class Deque

  attr_reader :first, :last

  def push(datum)
    if @last.nil?
      @last = Element.new(datum)
      @first = @last
    elsif @last == @first
      @last = Element.new(datum,@first)
      @first.prev = @last 
    else
      prev = @last
      @last = Element.new(datum,prev)      
      prev.prev = @last
    end  
  end

  def pop
    datum = @last.datum
    @last = @last.next if @last
    datum
  end

  def shift
    datum = @first.datum
    @first = @first.prev
    @first.next = nil  if @first
    datum
  end

  def unshift(datum)
    if @last.nil?
      @last = Element.new(datum)
      @first = @last
    elsif @last == @first
      @first = Element.new(datum,nil,@last)
      @last.next = @first
    else
      prev = @first
      @first = Element.new(datum,nil, prev) 
    end   
  end  

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I'm very confused by your naming - or perhaps you are. When pushing something onto a non-empty deque, you create a new `Element` and set its *next* element to be the preceding one. I.e. when examining the appended element, I'd see that its `next` is in fact the one before it. And vice-versa for `unshift`. It seems to work out (or I think it does) because you're at least consistent about the next-means-previous, and previous-means-next.
   Or you've simply got `push` and `unshift` (and `pop` and `shift` backwards. Which is think is the case.
2. You could make good use of `Struct` for your `Element` class. And I'd make it a private inner class, since it's not meant for external use

   ```
   class Deque
     # ...

     private

     Element = Struct.new(:datum, :prev, :next)
   end
   ```

   Saves you having to type the whole class declaration.
3. While `pop` and `shift` return the actual data, your `first` and `last` accessors return `Element` instances. I'd suggest that `pop/push/shift/unshift/first/last` all return data, while you use different methods/variables internally to get the `Element`-wrapped data. Say `head` and `tail`.
4. You don't need to check for `nil` as often as you do. Forgetting for at moment the `prev`/`next` confusion, your `push` method could be just

   ```
   def push(datum)
     if @last.nil?
       @last = @first = Element.new(datum)
     else
       @last = Element.new(datum, @last)
     end  
   end
   ```

As an alternative to your current approach, you could put some more logic into `Element` to clean up the code in `Deque`. I.e. give `Element` methods like `append` and `prepend` which create a new `Element` instance that's properly linked to the receiver. It avoids you having to set things from the outside.

```
class Deque
  def initialize
    @head = nil
    @tail = nil
  end

  def push(datum)
    if @tail
      @tail = @tail.append(datum)
    else
      @head = @tail = Element.new(datum)
    end
  end

  def pop
    return nil unless @tail
    datum, @tail = @tail.datum, @tail.prev
    datum
  end

  def unshift(datum)
    if @head
      @head = @head.prepend(datum)
    else
      @head = @tail = Element.new(datum)
    end
  end

  def shift
    return nil unless @head
    datum, @head = @head.datum, @head.next
    datum
  end

  def first
    @head ? @head.datum : nil
  end

  def last
    @tail ? @tail.datum : nil
  end

  private

  Element = Struct.new(:datum, :prev, :next) do
    def prepend(datum)
      raise "Can't prepend here" if self.prev
      self.prev = self.class.new(datum, nil, self)
    end

    def append(datum)
      raise "Can't append here" if self.next
      self.next = self.class.new(datum, self, nil)
    end
  end
end
```

The exceptions being raised in `prepend`/`append` are there to catch cases where you try to append/prepend something "in the middle" if the deque. Doing so would only modify one side of the linkage, causing the list to branch and things to go weird.

Of course, the simplest deque in Ruby is the built-in `Array`.

```
deque_instance = []
```

And done.

Comment: Regarding(2) Struct vs Named class, what is the real benefit?

Comment: @user663848 It's mostly syntactic sugar. You can either declare your own very basic class just to hold 3 read/writable variables, or you can use Struct to make such a class for you. It's still a named class (`Struct.new` returns a class), it's just a quicker way to create one when all you need it to do is hold a few variables.

Answer (score 3):

I'll second some of @Flambino's remarks: your next/prev naming convention is backwards, the `Element` class could be simplified down to a `Struct`, and your return types are inconsistent.

With linked lists, the special cases can be reduced by introducing a dummy element for the head.  This is doubly useful for a doubly linked list, which is what you have.

```
class Deque
  Element = Struct.new(:datum, :next, :prev)

  def initialize
    @head = Element.new(nil, nil, nil)
    @head.prev = @head.next = @head
  end

  def push(datum)
    element = Element.new(datum, @head, @head.prev)
    @head.prev = @head.prev.next = element
    self
  end

  # Returns nil if the deque is empty
  def pop
    element = @head.prev
    element.prev.next = @head
    @head.prev = element.prev
    element.datum
  end

  # Returns nil if the deque is empty
  def last
    @head.prev.datum
  end

  def unshift(datum)
    element = Element.new(datum, @head.next, @head)
    @head.next = @head.next.prev = element
    self
  end

  # Returns nil if the deque is empty
  def shift
    element = @head.next
    element.next.prev = @head
    @head.next = element.next
    element.datum
  end

  # Returns nil if the deque is empty
  def first
    @head.next.datum
  end
end
```